# What happens if no destination is defined after > (redirection)?

Tags: command-line, syntax

recently I wanted to read the man pages for mplayer. So I needed to type `man mplayer` in the terminal.

Yet out of clumsiness
I typed `man mplayer>`.

I know that I could redirect the output e.g. to a text-file with that command.

But can anyone tell me what exactly happens when I forget to define a destination, as I did with `man mplayer>` ?
Where is it redirected to, if at all?

I get the error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

in bash or

```
fish: Expected a string, but instead found end of the statement
man mplayer>
            ^
```

in fish.

Tnx a lot in andvance.
Rosika

My system:
Linux/Lubuntu 18.04.2. LTS, 64 bit

Comment: You got syntax error, output is not redirected without destination

Comment: @LeonidMew: Thanks a lot for the fast answer. O.K. that´s what I almost thought as well. But I wanted to be sure. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @LeonidMew Please consider turning your comment to an answer so that Rosika can accept the answer as correct and place the green check mark (✅) on the left margin of the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is simple: **You got syntax error**, output is not redirected without destination